# How to show array data in CakePHP drop-down?

Tags: arrays, cakephp, drop-down-menu

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Doctor] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [doctor_name] =>  Dr. Kazi Hasinur Rahman
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Doctor] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [doctor_name] => Dr.M. Zahid Hasan
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Doctor] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [doctor_name] => Dr.M.A.Malek
            )

    )
)
```

This is my array of doctors. I want to show doctor_name as dropdown and use id for query when form will be submit.

in my Doctor Model:

```
 public $displayField = 'doctor_name';
```

and my view is:

```php
<?php echo $this->Form->input('doctor_name', array('options' => $doctors)));?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use data from your model in dropdowns, a [find('list')](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list) is what you're looking for. In your Controller add:

```
$this->set('doctorNames', $this->Doctor->find('list'));
```

Because you've already set the `displayField` in your model, it will fetch that as the labels, the id's will be the values. Just as it should be. Also, if you follow naming conventions and set the variable name as `$doctorNames`, you no longer need to add the `options` part to your View, you can simply use:

```
$this->Form->input('doctor_name');
```

And it will produce a dropdown with all the doctor names in it.

Answer (score 1):

When getting the array of doctors, use `$this-> Doctor-> find ('list')`

This will return a key-value array.